# Detect whether a page is a product subcategory page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, categories

How can I detect whether current page is a product sub category page?

I've tried with the following but it will always print out "NO"

```
function is_subcategory($category = null) {
    if (is_category()) {
        if (null != $category){
            $cat = get_category($category);
        }else{
            $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
        }
        if ($cat->parent == 0 ){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (is_subcategory()){
    echo "YES";
}else{
    echo "NO";
}
```

Comment: Uhm yes, or atleast on frontend im looking at a product overview for a subcategory.

The code itself is added to header.php right after <?php wp_head(); ?>

Comment: `is_category` works for in built category not the product custom taxonomy!

Answer (score 6):

`is_category()` only check the built in post category. Product categories are custom taxonomies. So you need to use [`is_tax()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) instead of `is_category()` and [`get_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) instead of `get_category()`.

Check this example:-

```
function is_subcategory($cat_id = null) {
    if (is_tax('product_cat')) {

        if (empty($cat_id)){
            $cat_id = get_queried_object_id();
        }

        $cat = get_term(get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat');
        if ( empty($cat->parent) ){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also safe side instead of `get_query_var()` use [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/)

Comment: Great and clean answer. Is `$cat->parent == 0` safe to use? I've always used `$cat->parent == ''`.

Comment: Thank you! Well AFAIK with `==` `0` and `''` same thing. What do you say ?

Comment: Yup, both usually means _false_. I was just thinking (_should not think too much_) that maybe there are some edge cases with WordPress. I guess now I know better.

Comment: Okay. But I always relay on `empty()`. Perhaps I should edit my answer. Thanks :)